# Multi-threaded Nashorn: o.constructor === o.constructor gives false

Tags: javascript, multithreading, scala, java-8, nashorn

I'm experimenting with multi-threaded scripts loading and evaluation in Nashorn and get kind of shocking behavior:

```
// having some object o loaded in another thread
print(o.constructor === o.constructor); // false
print(o.constructor === Object); // false as well
print(o.foo === o.foo); // true - OK
```

How can this be possible within single script engine? `o` above is just an object created using object literal notation (in another thread). Printing `o.constructor` gives usual `function Object() { [native code] };`.

At the same time:

```
print({}.constructor === {}.constructor); // true
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

It turned out this was unrelated to multi-threading at all. See my answer below for details.

Comment: Each thread probably has its own copy of the Object constructor? Kind of like different windows in a browser? That is `window.frames[0].Object !== window.Object`

Comment: @JuanMendes I bet that's exactly what it is. Except ... well, if it's a reference to an "alien" object, I'm not sure how it works at all. It'd help to know more about what the OP has set up; like, is it one ScriptEngine or multiple?

Comment: Does it explain why o.constructor is not equal to itself?

Comment: @Tvaroh I don't know; it seems strange.

Comment: @Pointy this is just one script engine.

Comment: So different threads are sharing a reference to a single ScriptEngine instance and making calls into the JavaScript code? Wow.

Comment: @Tvaroh No it doesn't explain `o.constructor === o.constructor` being false. That is really weird

Comment: Yep, but the code itself is thread-safe. I'm just evaluating one file then pass the result to a function being evaluated in another thread.

Comment: @JuanMendes furthermore according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032656/does-it-make-sense-to-load-scripts-concurrently-in-java-8-nashorn-javascript-eng Nashorn is not thread-safe so it shouldn't create different globals (like Object constructor) for different threads.

Comment: In fact, I doubt this is threading-related. I tried setting my thread pool size to 1 and nothing changed.

Comment: Maybe `o.constructor` is `NaN` :) :)

Comment: @Pointy As I mentioned in the question, it's not. I will try to create a minimal reproducible sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out this does not relate to multi-threading at all. Here is a simple Scala program which reproduces the problem:

```
object Test extends App {
  val engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn")
  var o = engine.eval("({ foo: 'bar' })")
  var result = engine.eval("(o.constructor === o.constructor)", new SimpleBindings() {
    put("o", o)
  })
  print(result) // false
}
```

I was using `bindings` parameter incorrectly. Instead, I should take existing `bindings` and update 'em in-place. I'm still not convinced this should result in `o.constructor === o.constructor` to be false, but at least it works now. Corrected version:

```
object Test extends App {
  val engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn")
  var o = engine.eval("({ foo: 'bar' })")

  val bindings =  engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE)
  bindings.put("o", o)

  var result = engine.eval("(o.constructor === o.constructor)", bindings)
  print(result) // true
}
```

Comment: Whether this is expected behavior or not, it's certainly not intuitive, nor clearly documented. There's nothing I've found about Nashorn that explains why evaluating an object in a new bindings would behave differently than using the engine bindings. Good catch, though.